# Easiest way to spin up an Amazon EC2 cluster for use as a foreach backend

Tags: r, foreach, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I want to start a cluster of amazon EC2 machine for use a backend for the `foreach` package in R.  Ideally, I could do this all from the command line in R on my local machine, sending the relevant data and commands from the local R session to the remote cluster.

I know the [AWS](https://github.com/armstrtw/AWS.tools) package will help with this task, but I don't really know what to do after running the [startCluster()](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AWS.tools/AWS.tools.pdf) command. Segue also gets me part of the way there, but it's not a backend for `foreach`, it doesn't seem to support custom AMIs, and it doesn't currently support windows.  There is also the [deathstar](https://github.com/armstrtw/deathstar) package, which I haven't explored in-depth.

Has anyone else come up with a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Zach, the simple answer is that there's not a simple path to there from here :)

When I wrote Segue I hoped that someone would soon come out with something that would make Segue obsolete. Cloudnumbers may be it one day, but probably not yet. I have toyed with making Segue a foreach backend, but since I don't use it that way, my motivation has been pretty low to take the time to learn how to build the backend.

One of the things that is very promising, in my opinion, is using the `doRedis()` package with workers on Amazon EC2. doRedis uses a Redis server as the job controller and then lets workers connect to the Redis server and get/return jobs and results. I've been thinking for a while that it would be nice to have a dead simple way to deploy a doRedis cluster on EC2. But nobody has written one yet that I know of.

Comment: doRedis is actually what I had in mind when I wrote this question.  I'm picturing a relatively simple scenario: You create a custom "worker" AMI that, on bootup, starts R, creates n doRedis workers, and has those workers join a redis queue on a DNS you own (like from dyndns).  Then, you need an R script on your local machine that points your DNS to your local machine, starts doRedis using your queue, starts n worker machine, farms some computations to those machines, then shuts down those machines.  Or I can just wait and hope someone write `doEC2` soon...

Comment: yup, what you describe is what I've been churning mentally. I've just not built it yet :)

Comment: You should take a look at the deathstar package I added to my question.  It uses ZMQ rather than redis, but it seems pretty close to what we're looking for.

Comment: the problem is not having a package that handles communication. The problem is building the scripts that creates the clusters in the cloud easily. ZMQ does not help with building the cluster

Comment: it looks like the `AWS` packages does help with building the cluster.

Comment: only kinda-sorta. I believe it's just a simple wrapper to the AWS command line tools. So you can fire up an EMR cluster. But that's it.

Comment: It looks like the deathstar package has a function called zmq.cluster.lapply, which is similar to the elmrapply function in segue.

Comment: how can you tell? When I go to https://github.com/armstrtw/deathstar I just see a jumbled mess of markup.

Comment: It looks like the page is broken right now.  It was working last night!  Here's the code from a recent commit: https://github.com/armstrtw/deathstar/tree/77e00dc447b72fdd3a96f8e3d6f4dcde5a27989b, and here's the readme file: https://github.com/armstrtw/deathstar/blob/af51b7c572d940c725396d991933a137db31a76c/README.rst

Comment: Hey that looks really neat. But it's not a foreach backend either though. It seems to use the lapply() metaphor.

Comment: I contacted the developer, and it sounds like someone else is working on a `foreach` backend for deathstar, but it doesn't appear to be on github yet.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like bioconductr has a [slick tool](http://www.bioconductor.org/help/bioconductor-cloud-ami/#mpi) for spinning up an MPI cluster.  Once started, you can run `mpi.spawn.Rslaves()` and `mpi.parLapply` on the master node to farm computations out to the cluster.  However, I can't figure out how to get it to work with `doMPI`.